# `openssl` not working on `haproxy` docker image

Tags: docker

I'm writing a docker container to spin `haproxy` for load balancing.

this is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM haproxy:1.8

ENV DOCKER_IMAGE haproxy
ENV DOCKER_NAME loadbalancer
ENV TZ Africa/Tunis

ENV DOMAINS="local.loop"
#terminal size
ENV COLUMNS="`tput cols`"
ENV LINES="`tput lines`"

ENV HTTP_BIND_OPTS=""
ENV HTTPS_BIND_OPTS=""

USER root

RUN set -x && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libssl-dev rsyslog socat && \
    # setup files for haproxy logging
    touch /var/log/haproxy.log &&  \
    ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/haproxy.log && \
    # tiny helper to reload haproxy config
    printf '#!/bin/bash\nkill -s USR2 `pidof haproxy`\n' >> /usr/local/bin/haproxy-reload && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/haproxy-reload && \
    # Cleanup
    apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY ./etc/ /etc/

VOLUME /var/lib/certs

WORKDIR /etc

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
```

this is my `entrypoint.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit
set -o nounset

readonly RSYSLOG_PID="/var/run/rsyslogd.pid"

main() {

  for domain in $DOMAINS; do
    if [ ! -f /var/lib/certs/haproxy/${domain}.pem ]; then
      echo "Creating Self Signed Certificate for ${domain}"
      mkdir -p /var/lib/certs/haproxy/
      cd /tmp
      openssl req -x509 -nodes -subj "/CN=${domain}" -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout ${domain}-key.pem -out ${domain}-cert.pem -days 365
      cat "${domain}-cert.pem" "${domain}-key.pem" > /var/lib/certs/haproxy/${domain}.pem
      rm "${domain}-cert.pem" "${domain}-key.pem"
    fi
  done

  start_rsyslogd
  start_haproxy
}

# make sure we have rsyslogd's pid file not
# created before
start_rsyslogd() {
  rm -f $RSYSLOG_PID
  rsyslogd
}

# Starts the load-balancer (haproxy) with
# whatever arguments we pass to it ("$@")
start_haproxy() {
  # haproxy "$@"
  haproxy -W -db -f /etc/haproxy/
}

main
```

when trying to run the container I get:

```
Creating Self Signed Certificate for local.loop
/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh: line 15: openssl: command not found
```

I know that `haproxy` is compiled with `openssl` so the docker image should have `openssl` installed right of the batch.

Comment: add `openssl` to the software installed with apt-get (in the RUN section)?

Comment: Being compiled with libopenssl != having the OpenSSL executable installed. They're two different things. `libssl-dev` is just the library, not the executables.

Comment: I made sure I also installed `libssl-dev` installed

Comment: Yes, and libssl-dev _is the wrong thing_.

Comment: how should I do to correct it?

Comment: Install `openssl`. Not `libssl`, not `libssl-dev`, `openssl`. They're all built from the same source package, but the components get split out so people who only need the library can _install_ only the library, etc.

Comment: BTW, I found that `openssl` was the correct thing (despite not using Ubuntu myself) via the search functionality at https://packages.ubuntu.com/